# NextJS issue reading items already in local storage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage, next.js

On logging into my NextJS application, I am saving some user data to local storage.

I am trying to render this into a small component which always displays the users name. The issue i am getting is that it is only sometimes showing and other times it is displaying as `null` ... It seems when i log in, it displays as null, but when i reload the page it works.

This is what I have;

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';

export default function ProfileDisplay() {
    useEffect(async () => {
        const userName = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('profile'));
        console.log(userName);
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            {userName}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is probably coming as null initially because on your server side there is no "localStorage" object. And since you are calling **useEffect** with empty **dependency array** , it will not fire when username changes. So you should declare username outside the useEffect and put it in **dependency array** for listening to changes.

```
export default function ProfileDisplay() {
  const userName = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('profile')); // moved it outside the useEffect 
  useEffect(() => {
    if(userName)
      console.log(userName); // do stuff with username
    
}, [userName]); // it will fire when username changes

return (
    <div>
        {userName}
    </div>
)
}
```

Comment: if I move to outside the useEffect, it will be an error `localStorage is not defined`

Comment: You could add a null check `localStorage?.getItem('profile')`.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the `userName` variable in state and update it in your `useEffect` once its value is retrieved from `localStorage`.

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export default function ProfileDisplay() {
    const [userName, setUserName] = useState('')

    useEffect(() => {
        const profile = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('profile'));
        setUserName(profile);
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>{userName}</div>
    )
}
```

Comment: This method always sets null unless i reload the page

Comment: At what point do you save the user name to `localStorage`? What value does `profile` have when you log it inside the `useEffect`?

Comment: Once the user logs in, i set some tokens, and then it hits an endpoint to get user information and then stores it to localstorage